# Verification of @Input decorator with UglifyJsPlugin

Tags: angular

I have been trying to minify my code for production (everything works fine when I run webpack in dev mode).  The main difference is the `UglifyJsPlugin` plugin.  When I serve my project with that plugin I get this in the JS console:

```
polyfills.b0a99d4.bundle.js:5 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'articles' since it isn't a known property of 'feed-grid'.
1. If 'feed-grid' is an Angular component and it has 'articles' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'feed-grid' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schema' of this component to suppress this message.
```

However, I believe I am declaring my inputs correctly (especially since it works without this plugin).

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ArticleModel } from '../../models/article.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'feed-grid',
  styleUrls: ['./feed-grid.scss'],
  template: require('./feed-grid.html')
})

export class FeedGrid {
  @Input() articles: ArticleModel[] = [];

  constructor() {}
}
```

Am I missing something with this Uglify plugin and maybe declaring inputs for it?  I can find anywhere that talks about verification of @Input() or the inputs component attribute.  I am using rc5 if this helps.

Thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template parse is not working properly as it should and angular team has provided a work around on their docs for right now but hope fully it should be fix soon in webpack.config file add this

```
htmlLoader: {
    minimize: false // workaround for ng2
  },
```

Or

```
{
    test: /\.html$/,
    loader: `html?-minimize`
}
```

Try this also

Use mangle: false to explicitly disable mangling.

```
 new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({     
            // Mangling specific options
            mangle: false
        })
```

[Source](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#uglifyjsplugin)

[workaround from angular.io](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html#!#production-configuration)

Comment: I wasn't using htmlLoader, but UglifyJS. Could you just add it to your answer (set mangle: false) in the plugin settings https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#uglifyjsplugin